# NSOpenPanel triggers DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS layout error

Tags: cocoa

On macOS 10.12.3, this error

> [Layout] Detected missing constraints for .  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override. Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug. This error will only be logged once.

is produced immediately by this code:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.directoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/")
        openPanel.begin() { (result) -> Void in }
    }
}
```

So far, it appears that the open dialog works properly.  Since this code clearly has no hand in the layout of the open panel, is there anything that I can or should do to prevent this error?

As suggested in the error message, I set a breakpoint on `DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS` and determined that it is laying out an NSVibrantSplitDividerView when this occurs, but that doesn't seem to be useful information.

Comment: Similar question: [Swift - warning when choosing files (Cocoa)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25462675/4244136)

Comment: According to [Swift - warning when choosing files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25462675/4244136) this is a bug in NSOpenPanel. Nothing to be done.