# Detected missing constraints for NSTextView

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

I have created a Document-based application that should save an NSAttributedString with a image into a package. I ran the application and added a image to the text view and saved it. When I opened the file, a dialog box said "the document 'x' could not be opened" and this was printed to the console:

```
[Layout] Detected missing constraints for <NSTextField: 0x100b3f480>.  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully 
define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set 
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and later, 
you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override. Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug. This error will only be logged once.
```

Document.swift:

```
enum CookRecipesFileNames : String {

    case notes = "Notes.rtfd"
}

class Document: NSDocument {

    var documentFileWrapper = FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [:])

    var popover : NSPopover?

    var notes : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString()

    ...

    override class func autosavesInPlace() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func fileWrapper(ofType typeName: String) throws -> FileWrapper {

        let notesRTFdata = try self.notes.data(from: NSRange(0..<self.notes.length), documentAttributes: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFDTextDocumentType])

        if let oldTextFileWrapper = self.documentFileWrapper.fileWrappers?[CookRecipesFileNames.notes.rawValue] {
            self.documentFileWrapper.removeFileWrapper(oldTextFileWrapper)
        }

        self.documentFileWrapper.addRegularFile(withContents: notesRTFdata, preferredFilename: CookRecipesFileNames.notes.rawValue)

        return self.documentFileWrapper
    }

    override func read(from fileWrapper: FileWrapper, ofType typeName: String) throws {
        guard let documentNotesData = fileWrappers[CookRecipesFileNames.notes.rawValue]?.regularFileContents else {
            throw err(.cannotLoadNotes)
        }

        guard let documentNotes = NSAttributedString(rtfd: documentNotesData, documentAttributes: nil) else {
            throw err(.cannotLoadNotes)
        }

        self.documentFileWrapper = fileWrapper

        self.notes = documentNotes
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you set any constraints in Interface Builder, or programmatically?

Comment: set them in interface builder

Comment: Okay, I'll add an answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [NSOpenPanel triggers DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS layout error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41905599/4244136).

Comment: @Willeke no, not duplicate. That is about `NSOpenPanel`. Mine is triggered when I open a previously saved file if any images are in it.

Comment: How do you choose the file?

Comment: @Willeke I just double click the icon of my previously saved file and then the error is logged to the console

Comment: Ok, no `NSOpenPanel`. "Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug.". I think it is related to the dialog box.

Comment: @Willeke then why nothing goes wrong if there are no images in my text view?

Comment: I'm guessing: a document without images can be opened and you don't get the dialog box.

Comment: @Willeke Yup you're right

Comment: Unless you display "the document 'x' could not be opened" somewhere, your views aren't used yet and the contraints error is caused by the views in the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

The warning 'Detected missing constraints...' is a Build Warning, telling you that you have added constraints to a view, but not enough to determine x and y coords, and height and width for the view. If you add no constraints in IB (an option here is to remove them all), Xcode will tell the app to use the exact position and dimensions used in IB. If you add ANY constraints to a view, you must add enough to determine both coordinates and both dimensions. If you want to keep your constraints (this is the second option), go to IB, and look for the yellow or red warning error, at the top left: [image: See this screenshot]

This will give you a list of missing and conflicting restraints in the View Controller.

Comment: You're correct, sorry about the error in my answer. It's a Build Warning, and a common one. Do you have the warning arrow in IB?

Comment: No, I dont have it. See the photo here: [http://i.imgur.com/pLdBGKG.png](http://i.imgur.com/pLdBGKG.png)

Comment: Oh and it should be a runtime error, as I could successfully compile and save stuff, but I can't open it. If I don't add the image to the text field, I can successfully save and reopen the file. Therefore, I think there's something wrong with my code

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, and also that I don't think I can help. I've seen 'missing constraint' and 'can't satisfy constraints' warnings, hundreds of times, and it's always been a poor use of NSLayoutConstraints, on the dev's part. And if all of yours are in IB, none in code, then I have no idea what could be causing this. I'll leave this answer here, so that if you do determine that constraints are being added at runtime (i.e., in code), I can hopefully help.